# Visual Assist (Visual studio 2013) auto-suggestion not applying (TAB)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-assist

I'm not sure which hotkey I triggered, but I seemed to have disabled the TAB key auto typing the suggested code and it's really getting annoying. Does anyone know a fix for this?

For example:

```
class Class1
{
private:
    float Value;
public:
    void SetProperty(float Val) { Value = Val; }
};

Class1 Inst = new Class1;
Inst.Se /* <--- TAB here should auto complete, menu pops up but dosen't apply */
```

Comment: Does the behavior stay the same after you restart Visual Studio?

Comment: If you double-click on the suggestion instead of pressing Tab, is the suggestion applied then?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `Inst->Se`?

Comment: @MarkoPopovic Problem was solved after PC reboot. Looks like a VA bug :D

Comment: @MarianSpanik It's not the -no pun intended- point of the question lol

Comment: @Dirt113 I wouldn't wonder if the VAX refused to do auto-complete because of a syntax error (dot instead of an arrow). But as I see the problem was solved by the PC reboot - so it was typo in the question but not in the real program.